# $-1$, sum of squares and embedding in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In the proof of theorem 1.4, *Algebraic K-theory and Quadratic forms*, Milnor uses the following fact:

> If -1 is not a sum of squares, then F can be embedded in a real closed
>   field.

I thought of some examples and "counter-examples" of this proposition. For all finite fields $\mathbb{F}_p$, $-1$ is sum of $p-1$ squares (and this is also true for all field of characteristics $p$). All real algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ should satisfy this proposition too (since there exists $\mathbb{Q}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}$). $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$ by sending $t$ to any transcendental element of $\mathbb{R}$. It's likely that $\mathbb{Q}(T_1,...,T_n)$ can also be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$ by the same method.

Question (I'm sorry for multiplicity):

1. Is $-1$ a sum of squares in the field of formal series $\mathbb{Q}((t))$?
2. Can $\mathbb{Q}((t))$ be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$?
3. What are some real closed field rather than $\mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}$?
4. What might be a proof of the above fact?

Comment: I have to admit the fact that I typed "some" instead of "sum" made my day. :)

Comment: Not all algebraic extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$ can be embedded in a real closed field, e.g. $\Bbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: In 1 do you mean to ask is -1 a sum of squares?  (-1 isn't itself a square by $\mathbb{Q}((t))$ being the field of formal Laurent series: the leading term in $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty a_n t^n$ has to be with $n_0 = 0$ and then $a_0^2 \ne -1$.)

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. 3. Assume $t$ is sent to $\tau\in\Bbb R$. Construct then a power series that diverges at $t=\tau$..

Comment: ... and the same proof shows that any sum of squares the least degree term has positive coefficient, so $-1$ is not a sum of squares.

Comment: OK, now I see that my proof -1 isn't a square can fairly easily be modified to prove -1 isn't a sum of squares.

Comment: I made several edits thanks to your comments. I guess I can safely say that the fact is incorrect (unless more conditions are put on $F$)?

Comment: On 2 I think you could also argue that $1+nt = [(1 + nt)^{1/2}]^2 = [\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{1/2}{k} n^k t^k]^2$ must map to a positive number for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ which leads to a contradiction since $t$ cannot map to zero.

Comment: Why do you think the fact is incorrect?  All this line of reasoning shows is that the real closed field containing $\mathbb{Q}((t))$ is not $\mathbb{R}$ but rather some other real closed field.  (And it even can be chosen to have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ since $\overline{\mathbb{Q}((t))} \cap K$ is another real closed field that works, and $\overline{\mathbb{Q}((t))}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{Q}((t))$ which is the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I thought that real closed field means $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No, "real closed field" means an ordered field which satisfies the intermediate value theorem for polynomial functions.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Can you please explain the notation $K$? what is that field?

Comment: OK, I meant: if $K$ is a real closed field with a given embedding of $\mathbb{Q}((t))$, and we then embed the algebraic completion of $\mathbb{Q}((t))$ into the algebraically complete field $K(i)$, then $\overline{\mathbb{Q}((t))} \cap K$ (which is a subfield of $K(i)$) is also a real closed field which contains $\mathbb{Q}((t))$.

Comment: You can also view $\overline{\mathbb{Q}((t))} \cap K$ as being the set of elements of $K$ which are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}((t))$.

Comment: I recommend Introduction to Quadratic Forms over Fields by T. Y. Lam, published about 2005. https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-67/